# updating a column by a constant value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having difficulty with a simple issue.

I have a number column a typical value is say 192.123.

I want to add/subtract a single value to it, say -100.123.

I assume it is

```
Update table_name
SET column_name = (the original value - 100.123)
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use '+' instead of '-'. So that it will add or subtract based on the input value.

```
Update table_name SET column_name = (column_name  + Value_to_add_subtract)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the column_name in original_value

```
Update table_name SET column_name = (column_name  - 100.123)
```

Answer (score 0):

use columnName instead of original value

update table_name 
SET column_name = (column_name - 100.123)